# Frequency analysis of categorical/binary data

Tags: time-series, categorical-data, binary-data, fourier-transform

I want to do frequency analysis with a data set of consecutive binary values, such as "Rainy - Sunny - Rainy - Rainy - Rainy - Sunny - ...". Using this data, I want to extract the frequency (= the harmonic component) of sunny days. Is there a structured approach to do so? Assigning Sunny=1 and Rainy=0, and then calculating the periodogram returns plausible frequency components, but how does one interpret power spectra density in such case?

Comment: Your use of "frequency" has several possible--and natural--interpretations in this context, including *proportion of events* and *inverse period of a harmonic component of a signal.*  Could you clarify what you mean by it?

Comment: See "Spectral analysis for categorical data ... ", Biometrika 1993, V 3, pp 611-622.